# Processing data.frame that needs order and cumulative days

Tags: r, dplyr

With the small reproducible example below, I'd like to identify the `dplyr` approach to arrive at the data.frame shown at the end of this note.  The features of the `dplyr` output is that it will ensure that the data.frame is sorted by date (note that the dates `1999-04-13` and `1999-03-12` are out of order) and that it then "accumulate" the number of days within each `wy` grouping (`wy` = "water year"; Oct 1-Sep 30) that `Q` is above a threshold of 3.0.

```
dat <- read.table(text="
Date wy Q
1997-01-01 1997 9.82
1997-02-01 1997 3.51
1997-02-02 1997 9.35
1997-10-04 1998 0.93
1997-11-01 1998 1.66
1997-12-02 1998 0.81
1998-04-03 1998 5.65
1998-05-05 1998 7.82
1998-07-05 1998 6.33
1998-09-06 1998 0.55
1998-09-07 1998 4.54
1998-10-09 1999 6.50
1998-12-31 1999 2.17
1999-01-01 1999 5.67
1999-04-13 1999 5.66
1999-03-12 1999 4.67
1999-06-05 1999 3.34
1999-09-30 1999 1.99
1999-11-06 2000 5.75
2000-03-04 2000 6.28
2000-06-07 2000 0.81
2000-07-06 2000 9.66
2000-09-09 2000 9.08
2000-09-21 2000 6.72", header=TRUE)
dat$Date <- as.Date(dat$Date)

mdat <- dat %>%
          group_by(wy) %>% 
          filter(Q > 3) %>% 
          ?
```

Desired results:

```
      Date   wy    Q abvThreshCum
1997-01-01 1997 9.82            1
1997-02-01 1997 3.51            2
1997-02-02 1997 9.35            3
1997-10-04 1998 0.93            0
1997-11-01 1998 1.66            0
1997-12-02 1998 0.81            0
1998-04-03 1998 5.65            1
1998-05-05 1998 7.82            2
1998-07-05 1998 6.33            3
1998-09-06 1998 0.55            3
1998-09-07 1998 4.54            4
1998-10-09 1999 6.50            1
1998-12-31 1999 2.17            1
1999-01-01 1999 5.67            2
1999-03-12 1999 4.67            3
1999-04-13 1999 5.66            4
1999-06-05 1999 3.34            5
1999-09-30 1999 1.99            5
1999-11-06 2000 5.75            1
2000-03-04 2000 6.28            2
2000-06-07 2000 0.81            2
2000-07-06 2000 9.66            3
2000-09-09 2000 9.08            4
2000-09-21 2000 6.72            5
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```r
library(dplyr)
dat %>%
  arrange(Date) %>%
  group_by(wy) %>%
  mutate(abv = cumsum(Q > 3)) %>%
  ungroup()
# # A tibble: 24 x 4
#    Date          wy     Q   abv
#    <date>     <int> <dbl> <int>
#  1 1997-01-01  1997  9.82     1
#  2 1997-02-01  1997  3.51     2
#  3 1997-02-02  1997  9.35     3
#  4 1997-10-04  1998  0.93     0
#  5 1997-11-01  1998  1.66     0
#  6 1997-12-02  1998  0.81     0
#  7 1998-04-03  1998  5.65     1
#  8 1998-05-05  1998  7.82     2
#  9 1998-07-05  1998  6.33     3
# 10 1998-09-06  1998  0.55     3
# # ... with 14 more rows
```

Answer (score 2):

data.table approach

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dat, key = "Date")[, abvThreshCum := cumsum(Q > 3), by = .(wy)]
```

Comment: you are right. I forgot to set the data.table's key. fixed.